# Heroku Postgres Error: PGError: ERROR: relation "organizations" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord

I'm having a problem deploying my Rails app to Heroku, where this error is thrown when trying to access the app:

> PGError: ERROR:  relation "organizations" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"organizations"'::regclass
  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Anybody have any ideas? This is a first for me, especially because I've been working with Heroku for a year on other apps, and haven't see anything like this. Of course, everything works on local SQLite.

Comment: The organizations table doesn't seem to exist. did you run your migration?

Comment: Thanks @shreyas, yes, the migration was run, and this is the output: ==  CreateOrganizations: migrating ============================================
-- create_table(:organizations)
   -> 0.0175s
-- add_index(:organizations, [:organization_type], {:name=>"organizations_index"})
   -> 0.0054s
==  CreateOrganizations: migrated (0.0238s) ===================================

Comment: Also, when I log into the console and check:

>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
=> ["schema_migrations", "jobs", "organizations", etc...

Comment: Now that you have your organizations table created, are you still facing a problem?

Comment: Yes, the organizations table was already created when the problem occurred, thanks...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I had the same problem. To solve it, resetting the database is more easier.

- heroku rake db:reset ('heroku run rake db:reset' if you're on cedar)
- heroku rake db:migrate ('heroku run rake db:migrate' if you're on cedar)

Then, migration was done successfully for my case :)

### While this is a good solution in this context, don't do it on production. It will delete all the records from your database

Comment: IF you're running a Cedar app, the commands need to be:
`heroku run rake db:reset`
`heroku run rake db:migrate`
Then `heroku restart` and it should be fixed.

Comment: @TimD I'm running a Cedar app and the run is not required

Comment: I had to `rake db:drop` and then `rake db:create` also

Comment: And on the production database ?? You can't reset and lose data ¿?

Answer (score 21):

I've had the same problem until I realized that I had to do:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

:)

Answer (score 19):

According to my experience (Rails 3.1, Sedar stack) after running `pg:reset` and `db:migrate` you might have to run `heroku restart`.

Comment: I fought with Heroku for a good forty minutes before I thought to try this. Redeploying, dropping(reset) and migrating the database solved nothing.

Answer (score 7):

My heroku version:

```
heroku --version
#=> heroku-gem/2.29.0 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

In order to fix it just open your terminal and run:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm YOUR_APP_NAME
heroku run rake db:setup
heroku restart
heroku open
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also had to destroy and recreate my app. I had run a rake db:migrate with a migration file not committed and for whatever reason, the pg:reset wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using devise? I had this exact issue when upgrading to 2.0 - You have to manually change the migration file.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Answer (score 0):

Apparently deleting my entire app and then redeploying from scratch fixed it. I have no idea what the problem was.

Comment: This is not the most effective solution.  The other more highly rated answers are superior.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the symptoms were the same, but the root cause and remedy turned out somewhat different. Spent hours on this. Hopefully this post will save someone else those hours!
I am using:

- Heroku Cedar
- Rails 3.2
- [ActiceScaffold Gem](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold)

Everything runs fine locally on SQLite, but get the same PG error on Heroku. Turns out that ActiveScaffold somehow prevents Heroku push from successfully running rake tasks due to an error similar to above. So you get a cache 22 where you get the same error if you try to run *heroku rake db:migrate*  or similar.

Now the fix:

- Comment out code blocks similar to following from **all** controllers that use "active_scaffold":

  ```
  active_scaffold :<model_name> do |conf|
  end
  ```
- Commit, push to heroku
- `heroku run rake db:migrate`
- Verify that everything is fine by running `heroku run rails console` and then say creating a model and saving it.
- Now revert the changes (i.e. bring back the `active_scaffold` block above)
- commit, push to heroku
- you are in business!

Answer (score 0):

I keep my local setup as close to production as possible, including using a postgresql database, so I had this problem on my local machine. I can't delete my production database anyway. It turned out my issue was only in test, so I used: rake db:test:prepare to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of sifting through answer, I realized that when you specify

```
rails new MYAPP -database POSTGRESQL
```

it changes the .gitignore file, ignoring the entire `/db/ directory`, so my database was never getting pushed up to heroku.  Remove it with caution, or at least don't have your username and password in there where you push up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ran `heroku run rake db:reset` and `heroku run rake db:migrate` to fix the issue. I guess that I just hadn't run the proper migrations to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons for this error.  For my app, however, the issue was that I hadn't logged out of the app before I ran the migration (?).  So going to this path: 
 `http://name_of_my_app.herokuapp.com/logout` 
fixed the problem for me.