# Rails 3 db:reset and assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, asset-pipeline, pg

I made what I now see as a mistake (better now than later, not as good as never) of running `rake db:reset` on my local dev env to try to solve a problem I was having with assets production compilation(`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile)` referring to a PG ERROR summarized bellow.

```
PGError: ERROR:  relation "schools" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"schools"'::regclass
```

The tables get created properly and seeding works with exception of active_admin. I use Active_Admin that did not seed properly. My emails mysteriously stopped being sent and the assets compilation for production still fails with the same error. I am not sure what I can post here to help you understand the issue but if someone could help me tackle one at a time that would be much appreciated. Here are my issues in list form.

1. active_admin not seeding (I tried running: `rails generate active_admin:install` but that started to break things further so I reverted this.
2. PG ERROR on assets precompile for production persists.
3. Email stopped being processed (not using DJ)

Env.
Rails 3.1

------**UPDATE 00**------

*2 is Solved.* db:reset dropped all my tables but only migrated and seeded my development database so I also had to:

- run migrate and seed for production ( `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"`, `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV="production"`)
- before compiling production assets(`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting this question into 2 parts. The second part got better contribution and is where I found the solution for this as well.

Detailed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784766/failing-on-production-heroku-where-a-attrelid-schoolsregclass)