# Heroku - doesn't work "rake" command: PG::Error: ERROR: relation "roles" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, migration, rake

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I'll get this error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "roles" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"roles"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"roles"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum

Tasks: TOP => db:reset => environment
```

I've also tried to reset the database: `heroku run rake db:reset` but I've got the same error as above. It looks like the command `heroku rake` doesn't work. Also, I've tried to move my whole local database to Heorku - `heroku db:push` - and this is working. But I would need to run my migrations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failing on production/heroku: WHERE a.attrelid = '"schools"'::regclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784766/failing-on-production-heroku-where-a-attrelid-schoolsregclass)

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error you will see when running Rolify and migrating.

You need to check your Rolify initializer file `config/initializers/rolify.rb`.  if the command `config.use_dynamic_shortcuts` is uncommented, then comment it.  Push up your changes and then run `rake db:migrate`.  After you successfully migrate, then you can go back and uncomment the line.

The problem is that rails loads the initializer files and `use_dynamic_shortcuts` will throw an error if the database has not been migrated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you committed everything? Try `git status` then `git add .` then do a `git push heroku` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
heroku pg:reset
```

It will try to reset your database to a sane state. Then you can migrate and seed.

If you can't migrate, mybe your migrations are not correct, try to apply the schema:

```
heroku rake db:schema:apply
```

Comment: I got `Resetting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE (DATABASE_URL)... done` - then I tried to run my migrations and again the same error message.

Comment: Try applying the schema instead of migrating from scratch (edited)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have code in an initializer (or something similar) that is referencing a `Role` class - because the table doesn't exist when the environment is spun up (even if you're trying to set up the table!) it will generate an error.

Try removing the code referencing the Role class, migrating the database, then putting the code back in.