# Can't deploy to heroku [heroku log included]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm having trouble deploying to Heroku, I've installed postgresql but I don't think I've configured it properly. This may or may not be the problem, but I have a hunch it has something to do with it. please advice.

the git for the blog: https://github.com/Apane/Blogit_blog

Updated Heroku Logs

```
    2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="right1">
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= login_required class: "actions", id: "new_blog_post_link" do %>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <%= link_to t(:new_blog_post, scope: 'blogit.posts'), new_post_path %>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.941979+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered blogit/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (91.1ms)
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (unknown attribute: name):
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946665+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/blogit/posts/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_blogit_posts_index_html_erb__3752095678148312245_34603300'
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: </div>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.946326+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <% end %>
2013-05-25T02:32:07.997684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:32:07.997684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-05-25T02:32:10.467911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-05-25T02:37:19.248690+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-05-25T02:38:02.467323+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy de08b17 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:38:02.493201+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by "email"
2013-05-25T02:38:02.544564+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy de08b17 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:38:03.445329+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-05-25T02:38:04.208989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-05-25T02:38:06.350047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 41915`
2013-05-25T02:38:07.613671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:38:08.321413+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:08] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:38:08.321413+00:00 app[web.1]:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-05-25T02:38:15.184606+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:38:15.184606+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:38:15.187273+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:38:16.758556+00:00 app[web.1]: [Blogit]: Blogit::Configuration#rss_feed_language has been deprecated. You can remove this from your blogit.rb configuration file
2013-05-25T02:38:17.431528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:38:17.431823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-05-25T02:38:18.932239+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:18] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-05-25T02:38:18.932504+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=41915
2013-05-25T02:38:18.932239+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:38:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-05-25T02:38:19.138465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-25T02:38:19.286419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-05-25 02:38:24 +0000
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:41915
2013-05-25T02:38:24.702435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-05-25T02:38:24.865680+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Blogit::PostsController#index as HTML
2013-05-25T02:38:25.061058+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered blogit/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (130.6ms)
2013-05-25T02:38:25.061376+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 196ms
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (unknown attribute: name):
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="right1">
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-springs-1056.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=407ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= login_required class: "actions", id: "new_blog_post_link" do %>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <% end %>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <%= link_to t(:new_blog_post, scope: 'blogit.posts'), new_post_path %>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: </div>
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/blogit/posts/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_blogit_posts_index_html_erb___1859728747634219045_31435420'
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:38:25.063272+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
2013-05-25T02:39:31.009984+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by "email"
2013-05-25T02:39:35.228241+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: Awaiting client
2013-05-25T02:39:35.254224+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-05-25T02:39:36.715005+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-25T02:39:43.583619+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: Process exited with status 0
2013-05-25T02:39:43.598693+00:00 heroku[run.1589]: State changed from up to complete
2013-05-25T02:47:44.635791+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 3b2c0e0 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:47:44.659753+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by "email"
2013-05-25T02:47:44.704699+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 3b2c0e0 by "email"
2013-05-25T02:47:45.205793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-05-25T02:47:48.591029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 27123`
2013-05-25T02:47:49.862664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:47:50.836497+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:50] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:47:50.836497+00:00 app[web.1]:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-05-25T02:47:54.610704+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them 
in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:47:54.611109+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:47:54.611344+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-25T02:47:56.472610+00:00 app[web.1]: [Blogit]: Blogit::Configuration#rss_feed_language has been deprecated. You can remove this from your blogit.rb configuration file
2013-05-25T02:47:57.907795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-05-25T02:47:57.907795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:57] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-05-25T02:47:57.908723+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-25 02:47:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=27123
2013-05-25T02:47:58.197066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-25T02:47:58.851641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-05-25T02:47:58.851887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:27123
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-05-25 02:48:00 +0000
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-05-25T02:48:00.088867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-05-25T02:48:00.290164+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Blogit::PostsController#index as HTML
2013-05-25T02:48:00.460839+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered blogit/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (98.8ms)
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="right1">
2013-05-25T02:48:00.461055+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 171ms
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (unknown attribute: name):
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <% end %>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <%= link_to t(:new_blog_post, scope: 'blogit.posts'), new_post_path %>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= login_required class: "actions", id: "new_blog_post_link" do %>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: </div>
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/blogit/posts/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_blogit_posts_index_html_erb___1549385033592403810_36478100'
2013-05-25T02:48:00.462767+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:48:00.463077+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-25T02:48:00.471980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-springs-1056.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=421ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-25T02:48:01.026129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error logs, the problem is coming from

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
```

which is

```
@current_user ||= User.first || User.create!(name: "APane")
```

You are trying to create a new row in the User table passing in a name attribute on the user table, but it doesn't exist. In your schema, user does not have a name field. You will need to generate a migration to add it.

You may want to brush up on some basic understanding of rails applications as well. The [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) are very helpful.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to do it, albeit the blog functionality isn't being displayed on the Heroku launch. Do I have to upgrade the dynos to get functionality working on Heroku? I'd like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "upgrade the dynos" Are you testing your application locally at all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you run 'heroku run rake db:migrate'? It seems like Heroku doesn't see your User model, which means it might not yet be in the database.

Here's a similar question: [Heroku Postgres Error: PGError: ERROR: relation "organizations" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450930/heroku-postgres-error-pgerror-error-relation-organizations-does-not-exist?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks guys, I ran the migration but still getting an error - check the updated logs.

Comment: in your user.rb, try changing the name instance variable to self.name and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Webrick, I am pretty sure you should be using Thin for Heroku. Not sure if it will fix your problem though.

Comment: Add it your gemfile. gem 'thin'

Comment: Correction I guess they want unicorn now: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your `Gemfile` you have a mistake with the indention of `end` in your `:production` group.

Change this

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  end
```

to this

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Also, if you are using `sqlite` for development and `postgresql` for production and you are not sure about installing `postgresql` correctly. Do this

```
bundle install --without production
```

This will get you up and running on Heroku.

However, Heroku doesn't recommend running different databases in development and production because it can lead to hard to find bugs, etc. So it would be wise to figure out how to run postgresql in both environments soon. Hope this gets you started

Comment: Thanks, updated the original post..the problem persists. Id like to hear your thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: Actually, that did fix the error you that you had posted before you updated the log. The postgresql error. Now you have a different error `ActionView::Template::Error (unknown attribute: name):` Try to get this fixed in your development environment on your local machine. If you cant figure it out just post a new question. You should not morph questions after they have been posted. I'm happy to help

Comment: indentation is merely a convetion (a strictly enforced one, albeit), and it being off will not cause errors in unambiguous cases

Comment: Agreed. Just pointing it out. The `bundle install --without production` part fixed the error in the question. The error logs were than edited to a new error which you are proposing an answer to now. The question keeps changing when the real problem is getting things to work locally and then push to Heroku. I'm not sure the poster understands that.