# Only certain views rendering in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

So I just deployed an app to heroku.  It has two root pages, one for once the user is authenticated and the other for any person who visits the site.  The homepage loads fine, but after logging in, once the app is directed to the "authenticated root" I get the dreaded "We're sorry, but something went wrong" page.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?  Could it be an issue with Devise authentication?

Here's the first error from heroku logs

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "polls" does not exist
```

polls being a model in this app.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450930/heroku-postgres-error-pgerror-error-relation-organizations-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` after your deployments to migrate your database. Heroku does NOT run it as part of deployments.

Comment: Thanks John that was definitely part of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Another issue was when I ran a `git status` I had a list of all the erb templates that I had staged for deletion but hadn't manually remove.  For some reason, heroku was trying to render these views and not the HAML ones.  After I did git rm it worked.