# PG::Error: ERROR: column tutorials.tutorialcategory_id does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have two models 'Tutorial' and 'Tutorialcategory'

```
class Tutorialcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tutorials


class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tutorialcategory
```

Tutorials are associated with multiple categories like html,rubyonrails where html and ruby on rails are tutorialcategories

followings are migrations

```
class CreateTutorials < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tutorials,force: true do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.integer :rating
      t.string :videoid
      t.belongs_to :tutorialcategory

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateTutorialcategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tutorialcategories do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps null:false
    end
  end
end
```

All tutorials are listing properly on index page but when I see category page it gives me following error

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column tutorials.tutorialcategory_id does not exist
```

Comment: Did you remember to run `rake db:migrate` after create the migrations?

Comment: Yes I did it and i am able to add tutorials.

Comment: @Vikram did you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450930/heroku-postgres-error-pgerror-error-relation-organizations-does-not-exist) thread? Hope it would be some assist.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you named your model `Tutorialcategory` instead of `TutorialCategory` which follow Rails naming convention and make it easier to understand.

Firstly, rollback your db one step

```
rake db:rollback
```

Change your migration file to:

```
class CreateTutorials < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tutorials,force: true do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.integer :rating
      t.string :videoid
      t.belongs_to :tutorial_category, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateTutorialCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tutorial_categories do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps null:false
    end
  end
end
```

Run the migration again and edit your model to match with new schema.

```
class TutorialCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutorials


class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tutorial_category
```

Comment: yes he is not using correct naming conventions but still why error? it looks code is perfect isnt it?

Comment: @Guru Agreed. But when we have no clue, let try if follow naming convention make it works because of the Rails way: `convention over configuration`

Comment: I think I am very close to it, just not getting how to connect multiple to multiple. As per rails doc belongs_to is for one to many but I have many to many which can be done with has_and_belongs_to_many but then how will I get list tutorials for a category.

Comment: Question was for one to many and code also shows same. anyway if you want to achive m2m use has_many through. tell me if you stuck anywhere