# Heroku - undo rake db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I was having issues deploying my Heroku Rails app - and came across [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450930/heroku-postgres-error-pgerror-error-relation-organizations-does-not-exist) that suggested using:

```
heroku run rake db:reset
```

Which I ran without thinking, and of course my database was dropped and setup... and I no longer have any data on my heroku app.

Is there an easy way to get my database info back? I tried running

```
heroku run rake db:rollback
```

but haven't had any luck yet.

Anyone know of any easy solution to this? I kind of need this data, and most definitely cannot lose it! Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend asking heroku support for this help - they'll be able to give you the best advice.

Comment: You will find no solution in Rails, the data has been deleted. You must check for an Heroku backup.

Comment: Check out the [Heroku PG Backups documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#checking-backup-status) to see if a backup was made recently. It's your best bet.

Comment: Do you have same data locally on your machine?

Comment: No - this was all data that was added only on the heroku app... I've opened a ticket with Heroku, waiting to hear back now.

I also have no backup, might be SOL.

Answer (score 1):

```
rake db:reset
```

Can not be undone unless you have a database backup. If you found a database backup use the following to restore your database.

```
psql dbname < infile
```

**Tips:**
1. `rake db:rollback` does not get your database back. Instead, it rollbacks the last migration in your `schema_migrations` table.
2. Always create database backups for your production applications.
3. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss) it may come in handy.